# Obtaining a max row using EXISTS with additional condition/s

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I have a table in MySQL database namely `weight`. It can be viewed in the following snap shot.

The [weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC09N.png) table:

[image: weight]:

I need the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   weight w 
WHERE  w.weight_id IN (SELECT MAX(ww.weight_id) 
                       FROM   weight ww 
                       WHERE  ww.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60);
```

Linguistically obtaining a max row from the `weight` table from among the rows where the `weight` column has a value between 0 and 60 (for example).

---

I want the same query using `EXISTS()`. The following attempt is unsuccessful.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   weight w 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   weight ww 
               WHERE  w.weight_id < ww.weight_id 
                      AND ww.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60);
```

It returns all rows starting from the max row (if the `BETWEEN` condition (`AND ww.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60`) is omitted then, it returns a max from all the rows in the table but it is undesired. It should return a max row after applying a filter according to the `BETWEEN` condition).

A slightly modified version returns no rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   weight w 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   weight ww 
               WHERE  w.weight_id = ww.weight_id 
                      AND ww.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60 
                      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                     FROM   weight www 
                                     WHERE  ww.weight_id < www.weight_id))
```

Can I still have an alternative to use `EXISTS()`?

I'm using an ORM framework where a subquery is not supported in the `FROM` clause. Therefore, it would be far better, if a subquery in the `FROM` is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking `id` should only be used as a row identifier and not compared using `MAX()`.

If you want one row with the greatest `weight` between two values:

```
  SELECT id, weight
    FROM weight
   WHERE weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60
ORDER BY weight DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

I would not use `EXISTS` in this instance.

**UPDATE**

If you cannot use `LIMIT` then:

```
  SELECT id, weight
    FROM weight
   WHERE weight = (
    SELECT MAX(wi.weight)
      FROM weight wi 
     WHERE wi.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60
         )
```

will return the same providing there is no dupe on `MAX(weight)`

If you insist on using `EXISTS` then you could try:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM weight w 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
     FROM weight ww 
    WHERE w.weight < ww.weight 
      AND ww.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60
        )
    AND w.weight BETWEEN 0 AND 60
```

Comment: This query in the question is in turn, going to be wrapped with other queries in other related tables (more `EXISTS()` and may be joins) where the `LIMIT` clause is not going to work inside sub-select statements (I didn't post the actual scenario for the sake of simplicity).